# How to upgrade my Rails console to include the colors that are standard in Rails 6.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Whenever I fire up my Rails 6.1.3.1 app, it looks like this in the `rails c` prompts:

[image]

However, I just upgraded my Rails 5.2.3 app to Rails 6.0.4 and they don't look anything like this:

[image]

What exactly is this gem or setting called?

Comment: whats the output of `irb -v` in each of the projects?

Answer (score 0):

Realized that this was just because of the ruby version. After upgrading from Ruby 2.5.8 to Ruby 3.0.0, it was exactly like the terminal in the first screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

nice, in case you need it for future - refer to `awesome_print` gem

https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print

```
$ gem install awesome_print
```

### IRB integration

To use awesome_print as default formatter in irb and Rails console add the following code to your ~/.irbrc file:

```
require "awesome_print"
AwesomePrint.irb!
```

### PRY integration

If you miss awesome_print's way of formatting output, here's how you can use it in place of the formatting which comes with pry. Add the following code to your ~/.pryrc or your project's ./.pryrc:

```
require "awesome_print"
AwesomePrint.pry!
```